# Might use of rational numbers and calculations be beneficial for an ANN?

Tags: weights, gradient, vanishing-gradient-problem, precision

Rational numbers would help alleviate some gradient issues by not losing precision as the weights and the propagated values (signal) reach extremely low and high values.

I'm not aware of any hardware that is optimized for rationals. GPUs are all optimized for vector/matrix operations on floats. So, a couple of negatives are that it would likely double the storage and computation necessary for an ANN. But meh, hardware is constantly improving, and if there was value in creating a rational co-processor for AI, someone would build it.

I suspect an advantage would be greater precision and possibly mitigating some aspects of gradient issues.

What are the other pros and cons of an ANN using rationals?

Are there any research papers investigating the use of rationals in ANNs?

Comment: I just discovered a multi-precision library that supports GPU parallel calculations on rationals.  There is a port of GMP (GNU Multi Precision Library) to Cuda called CUMP. https://github.com/skystar0227/CUMP

Comment: My search for rational neural networks found research using "rational activation functions."  In other words, each neuron has a numerator function and a denominator function for activation. This does not imply the values in the network are stored or propagated as rationals.  However, I think the two concepts fit together nicely. https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.01902